# What is the correct way to create a violin plot that has one violin split by hue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, violin-plot

What is the correct way to create a violin plot that has one violin split by `hue`?

I've tried different approaches and it seems that the only way is to create a feature that shares the same value for every entry in the dataset. And pass that feature's name as `x`.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))

fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 1)
ax = sns.violinplot(x='feature', y='height',
              data=train_cleansed_height,
              scale='count',
              hue='feature', split=True,
              palette='seismic',
              inner='quartile')

fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 2)
ax = sns.violinplot(x='workaround', y='height',
              data=train_cleansed_height,
              scale='count',
              hue='feature', split=True,
              palette='seismic',
              inner='quartile')

fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 3)
ax = sns.violinplot(x=None, y='height',
              data=train_cleansed_height,
              scale='count',
              hue='feature', split=True,
              palette='seismic',
              inner='quartile')
plt.xlabel('x=None')
```

[image: Violin plot example]

But is it the correct way?

Comment: Is the middle plot ("workaround") the desired result? If so, I think you are correct and you have to trick seaborn with a single x-value. As far as I understand, `hue=` is supposed to be used *in addition* to `x=` and not instead.

Comment: It _seems_ so to me too. It's just I'd like to make sure, because passing the Series object with the same value across all indices feels strange. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `x` argument of `seaborn.violinplot` needs to be the data for the position. If a single position is desired, the data for `x` needs to consist of a unique value. If the same data is chosen for the `x` and the `hue`, `x` will be given two different unique values, hence two positions are chosen, as seen in the first plot.

Instead use a repeated label like

```
sns.violinplot(x=["some label"]*len(df),  ...)
```

to create a violin plot at a single position.

```
import numpy as np;np.random.seed(1)
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

a = np.concatenate((np.random.binomial(3,0.3,50)*2.2+1, np.random.rayleigh(3,50)))
df = pd.DataFrame({"height" : a, "feature" : ["A"]*50+["B"]*50})

fig = plt.figure()

fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
ax = sns.violinplot(x='feature', y='height',
              data=df,
              scale='count',
              hue='feature', split=True,
              palette='seismic',
              inner='quartile')

fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
ax = sns.violinplot(x=["AB"]*len(df), y='height',
              data=df,
              scale='count',
              hue='feature', split=True,
              palette='seismic',
              inner='quartile')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to control the color and linestyle of the quartile lines?